# Sums and products with tikzmath

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, tikzmath

I have numbered variables  like

```
\tikzmath{
\x{1}=2;
\x{2}=3;
\x{3}=7;
\x{4}=43;
\x{5}=1806;
 ..... and many more ....
}
```

which are all integer numbers.

I need to calc some sums and products of them;  for example: x1+x2+x3 and x1*x2*x3.

So how could this be done with the *tikzmath-library* in a consistent way (most likely with a loop).

I saw "tikzmath-loops" at the pgfmanual, page 704; 
[image] 
but I do not know how to build sums or products with that.

**Hint:** Would ne nice to do it with tikzmath, because many other stuff is with pgfmath or tikzmath.

**A MWE without a loop:**

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {math}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}% because some huge numbers...
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu, /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed,
%/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=0 % does not work
}

\begin{document}
\tikzmath{
\x{1}=2;
\x{2}=3;
\x{3}=7;
\x{4}=43;
\x{5}=1806;
}

\section{Sum/Product from 1 to 3}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\S{int(\x{1} + \x{2} + \x{3}}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\P{\x{1} * \x{2} * \x{3}}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\X{\P-\S}

Sum: S=\S

Product: P=\P

P-S=\X

\section{Sum/Product from 1 to 5}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\S{int(\x{1} + \x{2} + \x{3}+ \x{4}+ \x{5})}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\P{\x{1} * \x{2} * \x{3} * \x{4} * \x{5}}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\X{\P-\S}

Sum: S=\S

Product: P=\P

P-S=\X
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi!  I see that you call the library `math` but don't use it.  I think that the solution is there; the programming language is very basic, but you will be able to do your computations.